# Существует ли приставка "з"?

Tags: орфография, лексика, словообразование, морфемика, приставка

Почему в слове "первозданный" пишется буква "з"? Ведь приставки "з" не бывает?

Comment: @школяр-я, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Здесь корень "здан" (как в слове здание), от старого "зъдати" (строить).

Answer (score 4):

У Шанского

Первозданный (исконное слово) - сращение пьрво (сначала, прежде) и "зъданьныи" - созданный, от зъдати - строить.

Answer (score 1):

Перво[со]зданный.

В Псковско-Печерском монастыре читаем (на церковнославянском): "пещеры Богом зданные".